# Possible number of groups made from combination

Tags: combinatorics

Lets suppose I have a group $A$ with $n$ members and a group $B$ with $m$ members and $m<n$.

We create a group $C$ with $n$ members, where each member is **(a,b)**, where $a$ is a member from $A$ and $b$ is a member from $B$. Every member of $A$ must appear exactly once in group $C$.
Example:

$$A = \{a,b,c\}$$

$$B = \{1,0\}$$

$$C = \{(a,0), (b,1), (c,1)\}$$

My question is (ignore the example), how many different possibilities are there for group $C$, given an $A$ of size $n$ and a $B$ of size $m$?

Comment: This is isomorphic to the set of functions $A\to B$, since you require every element of $A$ to occur.  So, you need to choose one of $m$ possible outputs, for each of $n$ possible inputs; hence $m^n$.

Comment: What does this have to do with groups?  Are you thinking instead of *sets*?

Comment: How is this $C$ a group?

Comment: there are $m^n$ options since for each $a$ there are $m$ options for its corresponding pair.